# Glitchy mp4 File saved with Matplotlib Animation via ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, matplotlib-animation

I am attempting to save an `.mp4` file using `matplotlib.animation` to output some simulation results. The relevent section is as follows:

```py
ANI = FuncAnimation(fig, update, init_func = lambda : None, frames = range(0, 21300, 50))
ANI.save("[removed]/anim/v6 256 unforced 0.02.mp4", dpi = 600, fps = 30, writer = 'ffmpeg')
```

However, it appears that there is some issue in the produced `.mp4` file, as when I use macOS Quicktime to view the file, it pauses on certain frames, and restarts later on. It appears to consistently pause on the same frame a few seconds in. In order to check if Quicktime was the problem, I opened some random `.mp4` files I found in a family group chat, and did not have this issue.

I also tried viewing this `.mp4` file with VLC, which had no issue, and played without any glitches. The Slack media viewer built into the app pauses similar to Quicktime.

The following are all relevant versions:

- macOS: 14.2.1 (23C71)
- Python: 3.10.9 via Homebrew
- Matplotlib: 3.6.2
- ffmpeg: 6.1.1

If it would help, I can also provide the `.mp4` file itself, but I'm not quite sure how to upload it. I will be happy to provide any additional information as well.

Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with video rendering, but I would appreciate any help anyone could provide. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It appears that after changing the `dpi` to 200, this issue went away. Still not really sure why that would cause it.